# How to get document name from Berkeley DBXml

Tags: java, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-xml

Is there any command or JAVA API option to get name list of documents available in the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is an XQuery command you can run:

```
for $x in collection("users.dbxml") return dbxml:metadata('dbxml:name', $x)
```